# Generating/using table valued functions in Entity Framework 6.x with the help of EF Reverse POCO Generator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-generation, poco, t4

In my project I rely heavily on the EF Reverse POCO generator by Simon Hughes.

I have a TVF `GetItemSummaries` that takes 4 parameters and returns a table. This TVF is actually a replecement for a view (and the generator did not recognize the view due to lack of a PK, I assume). 
Now, running that in SQL Mgnt Studio works fine!

I **want to add that TVF to the .tt template** but I'm having trouble setting that up. There is (almost) no information on how to do this.

1. First of, I am separating the POCOs from the DBContext and *Configuration classes, and also the IDBContext interface.

What I've done so far:

2. I set     `IncludeTableValuedFunctions = true;` and include the **"EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions" Nuget Package** as instructed.
   From there, I am lost.
3. I tried to include the TVF names in the `TableFilterInclude` and `StoredProcedureFilterInclude` filter Regexes. No luck. The filter works for tables, but not for TVFs.
4. Then I tried adding the actual functions manually to the `DBContext` and `IDBContext` classes, but the returned type is a custom type of type `ItemSummary`, which wasn't defined. Etc. etc.

This is what I have added manually to the DbContext (which I hoped would be generated for me), but still doesn't work, sinece the DbContext doesn't know about the `ItemSummary` type:

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add( new FunctionsConvention<BusinessContext>( "dbo" ) );
}

[DbFunction( "BusinessContext", "FindItemSummaries" )]
public IQueryable<ItemSummary> FindItemSummaries( Guid customerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int programId )
{
    var customerParameter = new ObjectParameter( "customerId", customerId );
    var startDateParameter = new ObjectParameter( "startDate", startDate );
    var endDateParameter = new ObjectParameter( "endDate", endDate );
    var programIdParameter = new ObjectParameter( "programId", programId );

    var oc = ( ( IObjectContextAdapter ) this ).ObjectContext;
    var query = String.Format( "[{0}].{1}", GetType().Name, "[FindItemSummaries](@customerId, @startDate, @endDate, @programId)" );

    var result = oc.CreateQuery<ItemSummary>( query, customerParameter, startDateParameter, endDateParameter, programIdParameter );

    return result;
}
```

Bottom line is, I do not understand how to set this up. Has anyone done this before? How and where does "EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions" Nuget Package come into play? I do have read their blog post on that topic

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just in case - here is the post explaining how to map things up I wrote when I published the package https://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/ and there is a follow up for more features shipped later: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/08/11/the-beta-version-of-store-functions-for-entityframework-6-1-1-code-first-available/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved after updating the POCO Generator to version 2.18.1
The TVFs then appeared in the DbContext as expected.